# Servidor sql en nginx ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, nginx

Buenas me encuentro con un problema de configuración del servidor de mysql.

Lo estoy instalando en un servidor ubuntu con nginx. Creo, ya que es mi primera vez que lo estoy haciendo correctamente.

**Instalamos mysql**

`sudo apt install mysql-server`

`sudo mysql_secure_installation`

Yo le digo que no a la hora de instalar el plugin, configuro una nueva pass y listo.

**Luego entramos por ssh a mysql**

`sudo mysql`

**Comprobamos los usuarios**

`SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;`

**Le definimos un pass al root y quitamos lo de `auth_socket`**

`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';`

**Luego aplicamos todos los cambios**

`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Luego ya me conecto por ssh al mysql de este modo `mysql -u root -p` sin ningún problema, de hecho puedo crear tablas y demás, el problema me viene al conectarme con el programa `navicat`, que me devuelve este mensaje.

```
2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '82.223.98.245' (61 "Connection refused")
```

Ya no se muy bien que puedo hacer si en un sitio si me conecta pero en otro no. :S Alguna sugerencia???

Comment: le configuraste el [tunel ssh al navicat](https://www2.navicat.com/manual/online_manual/en/navicat/rv_manual/SSHSettings.html) ? sin el tunel ssh, el mysql no te toma el user como local ( y sólo tiene acceso local `@'localhost'`)

Comment: si pongo el tunel ssh me conecta el primer punto ssh, pero no al servidor @aloMalbarez